How to get a Drawable or DrawWindow from a DrawingArea in Haskell Gtk2Hs Gtk3
I want to draw into part of a window in Haskell+Gtk2Hs+Gtk3. It's an app to change images from one cartographic projection to another, for doing things with all the maps you find across the internet, like Wikipedia. First the user has to mark out some lines of latitude and longitude on the image
So I've created a window with glade with a DrawingArea in it called "area"
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Widget
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Misc.DrawingArea

main = do
   initGUI
   builder <- builderNew
   builderAddFromFile builder "Atlas.glade"
   window <- builderGetObject builder castToWindow "window"
   area   <- builderGetObject builder castToDrawingArea "area"
   on area   exposeEvent  (drawGrid area)
   --on window destroyEvent $ \e -> do 
   widgetShow window
   mainGUI

lamaziOfSph (psi, theta) = (2 * cos (psi / 2), -theta)
sphOfLamazi (r, theta) = (2 * acos (r / 2), -theta)
cartOfPol s (r, theta) = (r * s * sin theta + s, r * s * cos theta + s)

drawGrid area = do
   let t = cartOfPol 100 . lamaziOfSph
   d <- eventArea
   drawWindow <- drawingAreaGetDrawWindow area
   --sequence $ concat $ crossWith (\x y -> drawLine d gc (t (x, y)) (t (x + 10, y))) [-180,-170..180] [-90,-80..90]
   --sequence $ concat $ crossWith (\x y -> drawLine d gc (t (x, y)) (t (x, y + 10))) [-180,-170..180] [-90,-80..90]
   return 

But I get the error message:
ghci> :re
[5 of 5] Compiling Map              ( Atlas.hs, interpreted )

Atlas.hs:268:14: error: [GHC-88464]
    Variable not in scope:
      drawingAreaGetDrawWindow
        :: transformers-0.6.1.0:Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
             (GHC.Ptr.Ptr EExpose) IO a0
    |
268 |    window <- drawingAreaGetDrawWindow
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, four modules loaded.

EDIT: gtk3-0.15.9/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Widget.chs contains this:
module Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Widget (

#if GTK_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
  widgetGetDrawWindow,
#endif


The drawingAreaGetDrawWindow and related functions have been removed in GTK 3. I'd suggest looking at the Gtk2Hs carsim demo to see how to do custom rendering:
https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/blob/62896f21bdc016ce2f76a464bee2d6410d7683bc/gtk/demo/carsim/CarSim.hs#L227-L235

Hmm, get the same error with widgetGetDrawWindow. I looked at the source for gtk3 and found that that function is only included if GTK_MAJOR_VERSION < 3

Ah, my bad. I've updated my answer.
